# Custom View onDraw is constantly called

Tags: android, view

I have a custom view which I override the onDraw method to draw bitmaps using the canvas.

I can't really post any code because its quite long and complicated.

I put a log in the onDraw method, and I see that it never stopped being called.

My question is, what can trigger the onDraw method except calling invalidate on the view or its ancestors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the issue. I called `getWidth() and getHeight()` in the `onDraw()` method

Comment: Strange. I looked at the source code for View.getWidth() and View.getHeight() and neither method invalidates the view. It is also quite natural to call those method in onDraw().